# Unable to handle Shadow Element

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I am trying to print nested shadow element text using below code but no luck. I have tried to use same code throough console windows and its giving me expected text.

[image]

**Code :**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class ShadowRoot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        WebDriver driver;
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*", "ignore-certificate-errors");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

        // browser type and chromedrover.exe path as parameters
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        String url = "http://watir.com/examples/shadow_dom.html";
        driver.get(url);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        //      js.executeScript("document.querySelector('#shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('input').value='username'");
        js.executeScript("document.querySelector('#shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_content > div').innerText");

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't do a console.log in your executeScript. You're just evaluating document.querySelector... but doing nothing with what it gives back.

Comment: No, its not working with console.log

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the web page you are testing against?

Comment: Its already provided in the code

Comment: Based on [this](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.2.0/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) `executeScript` returns a Boolean, Long, String, List, WebElement, null. Can you not store this result in a variable and use system.out.println? Or is the result `null`?

Comment: I have tried that but getting Nullpointer Exception

Answer (score 0):

Your script `document.querySelector....innerText` seems to just be accessing the value and doing nothing with it. If you want to print the value in the browser console, you need to wrap it with [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

```java
js.executeScript("console.log(document.querySelector('#shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_content > div').innerText)");
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I already tried that but but its not working

Comment: Are you able to print any DOM content via `executeScript()`? If not, are you sure the script is being executed after the DOM, including shadow elements, has fully loaded? Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I am trying to execute script using java code through intellij . please refer above code section

Comment: I understand your goal, but I'm wondering if you have some race condition in your code. Check out the [Waits Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) in Selenium to learn more about how this can happen. So does the version with `console.log` print anything to the browser console, like `undefined` or some runtime error?

Comment: I have already tried Thread.sleep(); before posting here but no luck yet

Answer (score -1):

In selenium it returns as `webelement` you can use `.getText()` or `.getAttribute()` to get the value.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

WebElement shadowElement=js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_content > div')");
System.out.println(shadowElement.getText());
System.out.println(shadowElement.getAttribute("textContent"));
System.out.println(shadowElement.getAttribute("innerText"));
```

---

Inline this should work as well

```
System.out.println(js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_content > div')").getText());
```

Or

```
System.out.println(js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_content > div')").getAttribute("textContent"));
```

Comment: Same code I have tested with python works fine. `print(driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('#shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_host').shadowRoot.querySelector('#nested_shadow_content > div')").text)`